# update sql database by datagridview

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008

I have made a C# prog where I have a button(named insert) and a datagridview. I have input a cmd where if I enter a new value in dvg new row then after clicking insert button a msg box is shown depicting the values i hv entered..now i want a 2nd button named update..so dat when I click on it after inserting new values the new values get updated in my sql database.

Here is the snipet of my code-

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 //InsertInfo();


 foreach (int rowIndex in lstNewRows)
 {

 MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].Value + "; " +
 dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].Value);
 }

 lstNewRows.Clear();
 }

 private void dataGridView1_DefaultValuesNeeded_1(object sender, DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {

 lstNewRows.Add(e.Row.Index);

 }
private void updateInfo()
 {

 String strConnection = "Data Source=HP\\SQLEXPRESS;database=MK;Integrated Security=true";


 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
 using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(strConnection))
 {
 using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
 {
 int rowIndex;
 cmd.CommandText = @"UPDATE tble SET " +
 "name = @name, " +
 "number = @number" = (int)dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value + " ";

 cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "name");
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@number", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "number");



 cmd.Connection = sqlConn;



 using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter())
 {
 DataTable dtRecord = new DataTable();
 da.UpdateCommand = cmd;
 da.Update(dtRecord);

 }
 }

 }
 }

 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 updateInfo();
 }
 }
```

}

Comment: And what is your question here..?

Comment: why are you passing parameters like this `cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "name");
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@number", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "number");` Change the cmd.Parameters to `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@number, numberValue)` do the same for the name param for starters

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have problem with updating values of row. Your `updateInfo();` is wrong in many places, this is correct version:

```
String strConnection = "Data Source=HP\\SQLEXPRESS;database=MK;Integrated Security=true";
//SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnection); not needed
using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(strConnection))
{
      using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
      {
            int rowIndex = 1; //row index to update?
            var number = Int32.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString());  //assuming Cells[0] holds number
            var name = dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();                 //as above
            var id = Int32.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString());      //get id
            //your old command text was completly wrong
            cmd.CommandText = @"UPDATE tble SET  name = @name, number = @number where id =  @id"; //id and @id is key for row to update
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", name);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@number", number);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", id);

            cmd.Connection = sqlConn;
            sqlConn.Open();

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }

}
```

I changed your command string for one that works. Also in your original code you did not retrieve id of row to update, so I added markup for that, which you should change for correct one (variable `id`).

Hope this helps :)

Comment: no it's nt working it is showing 2 errors-                     1)Argument '1': cannot convert from 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' to 'string'                                                          2)Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.SqlCommand(string)' has some invalid arguments 
plz help! :(

Comment: You are right, my mistake. I changed code above: changed `using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlConn))` to this: `using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())` and also added this line `cmd.Connection = sqlConn;`

Comment: sir , it is showing an format exception in the statement

 var number = Int32.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString()); 

it is saying input string is not in correct format...plz help :(

Comment: n plz help me write dis update portion of code in try-catch form..im new to c# programming...

Comment: using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlConn)) it is showing 2 errors in dis staement..hw to write it correctly?

Comment: You have to change those values, I just tried to guess in which cells those are.